# Elasticsearch 6.2 - how to format date (epoch) field in yyyymm string in painless inline scripting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-6

In Elasticsearch 6.2, I have an index where there are two timestamp fields as follows:

```
"start_ts":  { "type": "date", "format": "epoch_second"  },                       
"end_ts":    { "type": "date", "format": "epoch_second"  }
```

In my painless inline script, for some calculation, I want to convert them (`doc["start_ts"]` and `doc["end_ts"]`) to this string format (`yyyymm`). Any idea how can it be done? I could not find any documentation for formatting in ES official documentation.

Comment: Take a look at the answer if this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864201/elasticsearch-painless-manipulate-date

Answer (score 1):

```
doc["end_ts"].toString("yyyyMM")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't work, just add `.value` to it.
i.e,

```
doc["end_ts"].value.toString("yyyyMM")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! JYou shouldn't refer to another answer as "above", since it's not sure that it will be displayed above. Instead, include the necessary information in your post.